# Access to WiFi connection settings on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi-configuration

I need to connect to my university's WiFi, which is eduroam, through TTLS or PEAP with my credentials.

Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon only shows the option after the connection is established, so I can't configure it to connect.  This is what I mean:

[image: This is what I mean]

Is there another way to configure specific network connections?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mint but I'm sure you can click the dog wheel to change settings.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out the way to configure the connection parameters before connecting was through adding a network with the ssid.
In my case with the "+" button, select wifi connection and SSID "eduroam", and proceed to the security settings.